# Android - Two buttons in same line filling the whole width

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I have a little problem defining a Relative Layout. I have a List View with scroll and two buttons always visible at the bottom of the list view. I just would like my two button have 50% of the width, filling the line. This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/testbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/testbutton"
        android:text="Cancel"/>

    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/LstPeriodOptions"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_above="@id/testbutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to introduce the buttons in a Linear Layout and give the gravity=1 with width=0dp but in that case the ListView dissapears. Could you help me please?

Sorry for my english. This is the result I would like to have:

[image: Result]

Thanks a lot, best regards.

EDIT: This is what I tried with Linear Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/container" >

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/testbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Guardar" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/testbutton"
            android:text="Cancelar"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/LstPeriodOptions"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_above="@id/container" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How did you have the `LinearLayout`? That should have worked.

Comment: if you don't want to use the obvious linearlayout, the trick for this is to put an 0-width view with centerHorizontal, and align the buttons on it

Comment: I edit the question showing how did I try, but it is not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Did you try with your `LinearLayout` in this way because this should work. Note all of the property changes. Since I don't know how yours was, I can't point out all of the differences.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/btnLL"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/testbutton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancel"/>
  </LinearLayout>
    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/LstPeriodOptions"
        android:layout_above="@id/btnLL" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try out as below to set your button in `LinearLayout` and set it below your `ListView`:

> ```
>       <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/laytbtns"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/LstPeriodOptions" >
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/testbutton"
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:text="Save"/>
>         <Button
>              android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:text="Cancel" />
>     </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: Try to give the Linearlayout `android:weightSum="1"` and give both the button's weight `0.5`

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/LstPeriodOptions"
        android:layout_above="@id/testbutton" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/laytbtns"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LstPeriodOptions" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/testbutton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Save"/>
        <Button
             android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```