# How to fill a full line in a vertical LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

This is my first app so sorry I know its not that good. My english neither.
I got a problem with my xml design: I want 2 `Button`s and 2 `TextView`s in one line and to fill the whole line. At the moment it looks like that:

[image]

but it gets even worse:

[image]

My code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="-" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="+" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="-" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="+" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="-" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="+" />

    </LinearLayout>
<!--
   skipping additional rows of identical structure
-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Two buttons in same line filling the whole width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137503/android-two-buttons-in-same-line-filling-the-whole-width)

Comment: try to use constraint layout instead of linear layout for responsive layouts 
 https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you should try for each of your `LinearLayout` :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="4"  // number of sub items
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="-" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="+" />
```

Also, you should take a look at [RecyclerViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) and create your own adapter and rows. It will be much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use wrap_content on the children of the linear layout. there are 2 solutions to your problem one is to use match parent on the text views and add gravity centre to them like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="-" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="centre"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="centre"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="+" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And another solution is to use a constraint layout with allows you to spread the child views using chains.